# Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, navigationview, android-navigationview

When I run app on Android I get this message:

```
08-20 17:38:26.542 5016-5016/? E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aplikacija.android.bluetoothscanner/com.aplikacija.android.bluetoothscanner.Activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line ##30: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2550)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5615)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.aplikacija.android.bluetoothscanner.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6362)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2550) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5615) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.CustomTheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/navigation_action"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/content_scan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/add_room_include"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.aplikacija.android.bluetoothscanner"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.ScanActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.ManageActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.ListRoomsActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.EditDataActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.ListConnectionsActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme"></activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.aplikacija.android.bluetoothscanner.MyBluetoothReceiver"></receiver>

</application>
```

**navigation_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="Navigation bar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.aplikacija.android.bluetoothscanner.Activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.aplikacija.android.bluetoothscanner.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mToolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void manageRoomsOnClick(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

**navigation_action.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/nav_action"
                                   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                                   android:orientation="vertical"
                                   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**content_scan.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scan"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutContentMain">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/scanning_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-87dp">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_view"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnScan"
            android:layout_width="187dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:text="Start scan"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/includedLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="312dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp">

        <include
            layout="@layout/list_connections_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnViewConenctions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="View Connections"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_stop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:text="Stop"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?
I know that here on Stackoverflow is many questions with the same problem.
I tried some of their answers but I got the same exception.
Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you also post the java file in which you are getting this error

Comment: @UmangBurman I added MainActivity.java

Comment: `@menu/navigation_menu` or `@layout/navigation_header` might be missing.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I looked at the files and they are here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to import the support library

go to your app>build.gradle in dependencies

```
 dependencies{
     implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'}
```

Comment: Try to remove the app:menu at navigation view

Comment: Thanks. I found problem in "navigation_menu.xml"

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the layout xml files for @layout/navigation_action & @layout/content_scan.
I think you are having some vector drawables issues for pre-lollipop devices within these layout files.